# Why is Selenium web driver crashing when attempting a navigation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selenium, testing

**Situation :**

To run integration tests on our ASP.NET MVC application, we chose Selenium's Web Driver.

**Problem :**

When running the tests from VS2015 using Internet Explorer Driver, the console displays an error message (see screenshot below).
Simultaneously, the browser opens and closes. The console freezes. Then, Visual Studio displays a StackOverflow exception message :

[image: Selenium console test crash screenshot]
**Diagnostic :**

- The test crashes as soon as the driver attempts a navigate action in the app.

  ```
  [Test]
  public void PerformNavigation()
  {
      Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(GetAbsoluteUrl("/")); // <-- The test crashes here
  }
  ```

  However an external url works.

  ```
  [Test]
  public void PerformNavigation()
  {
      Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com"); // <-- This works
  }
  ```
- It seems that the web driver is redirected forever until a stackoverflow exception occurs (HTTP 302).
- In debug mode, I can not find the main project's assembly (the one we are testing) in the modules window. It seems that the test project has some trouble loading this specific assembly : all other assemblies are here. I did not find any reason why an assembly couldn't be loaded.

**Question :**

I could not find any help on Google or SO. Our problem is very specific and may be a combination of issues.

So how can I make these integration tests work ?

Or at least : how can I perform a more precise diagnostic on this issue ?

---

**UPDATE :**

I eventually found out that the annotations before my controller methods were interfering with my tests. We use these annotations to check the user rights (here the user can read or update missions) :

```
[AuthorizedFunctionalities(Functionalities = "Mission_R;Mission_CUD")]
```

However I find it strange that these tests can not work with such annotations. They work well in debug mode but not through web drivers.
I'll try to investigate further.

Comment: IIS express has little to do with selenium, why the screenshot?

Comment: I use IISExpress' console output to know what is going on (requests, http state code...)

Comment: You need to make a driver variable did you do that?

Comment: Also load it from a location

Comment: Did not see your comment (//works)

Comment: @EpicKip Yes I did declare a driver variable (InternetExplorerDriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found out that the annotations before my controller methods were interfering with my tests. We use these annotations to check the user rights before the controller's methods:

```
[AuthorizedFunctionalities(Functionalities = "MyFunctionalities")]
```

By removing these anotations, the tests work. I still need to know why the web driver doesn't like these.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the assembly (.dll) dynamically, staight in the C# code, at the beginning of the tests.
To do so, you can use the following line of code :

```
Assembly.LoadFile($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\YourDLL.dll");
```